# How to convert for loop to foreach in typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, foreach

Is there any way to convert the following for loop into forEach? I checked for solutions in SO, but could not find anything related to mine.

```
private wasFormChanged(currentValue) {

const fields = ['givenName', 'familyName', 'email', 'username'];
for (let i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
  const fieldName = fields[i];
  if (this.user[fieldName] !== currentValue[fieldName]) {
    this.disableButton = false;
    return;
  }
}
this.disableButton = true;
}
```

Comment: have you used Array.forEach?

Comment: Yes.. it performs totally different from for loop. Can you provide a code snippet of array.foreach for the above code?

Comment: I haven't notice this post already has the answer check that. For your case put 'this.disableButton=true' as first line of the function, and when condition match inside 'forEach' loop throw an exception to break out from forEach method. Hope this will help you.